# How do I format the horizontal axis labels on a Google Sheets scatter plot?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

The settings for the vertical axis on a Google Sheets scatter plot provide an option for selecting or customizing a format for the labels, but no corresponding option is provided for the horizontal axis.

For example in the following chart, I have successfully changed the default decimal formatting on the vertical axes to integers, but can't change the "YYYY-MM-DD" formatting on the horizontal axis to simply "YYYY":

[image]

How do I format the horizontal axis labels on a Google Sheets scatter plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper column (it can be adjacent to your your data, or anywhere else in your spreadsheet). Make the cell values = "Release Date" values, give the data a header, then format the data as YYYY.

If the column isn't adjacent to your data, create the chart without the X-Axis, then edit the Series to include both data sets, and edit the X-Axis to remove the existing range add a new range being your helper column range.